# Перевести текст к другому виду в Python

Tags: python, массивы, текст

Имеется большой файл со строками, строки группируются уникальными начальными данными:

```
встретились кошка и собака они ели рыбу  
встретились кошка и собака они ели крысу  
встретились кошка и собака они ели сыр  
встретились кошка и собака они ели кашу  
встретились кошка и собака они ели картошку  
встретились кошка и собака они вместе играли  
встретились кошка и собака они вместе дрались  
встретились кошка и собака они вместе ссорились  
встретились собака и птичка они ели ряженку  
встретились собака и птичка они ели рябину  
встретились собака и птичка они ели траву  
встретились собака и птичка они вместе танцевали  
встретились собака и птичка они вместе гуляли  
встретились корова и коза они ели рябину  
встретились корова и коза они ели траву  
встретились корова и коза они вместе танцевали  
встретились корова и коза они вместе гуляли
```

и тд, еще 1000 связанных таких строк (дерево)

на выходе я должен получить

```
Случай 1:  
Встретились: кошка, собака  
Ели: рыбу, крысу, сыр, кашу, картошку  
Делали: играли, дрались, ссорились  

Случай 2:  
Встретились: собака, птичка  
Ели: ряженку, рябину, траву  
Делали: танцевали, гуляли  

Случай 3:  
Встретились: корова, коза  
Ели: рябину, траву  
Делали: танцевали, гуляли
```

Необходимо сделать уникальность на основании начала предложения и привести к СлучайX.

Пробовал построчно обработать:

```
import os
import subprocess
with open("few_animals.txt") as animals:
  uniq_line = "none"
  for set_animals in animals:
    if set_animals.startswith('встретились'):
      set_line = set_animals.split()
      uniq_line_tmp == "".join(set_line[:2]) == "".join(set_line[:4])

      if (uniq_line_tmp != uniq_line):
        animal1 = set_line[2]
        animal2 = set_line[4]
        print('встретились "', animal1, '" "', animal2, '"' sep='')
      uniq_line = uniq_line_tmp

dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
new_dir = os.chdir(dir)
d = input("Нажмите Enter для выхода")
```

Не могу зациклить.

---

На самом деле нужно распарсить конфигурационный файл в одном формате и на основе его создать конфигурационный файл в другом формате.

Так выглядит на джунипер:

```
set security policies from-zone untrust to-zone nprch policy term01 match source-address any
set security policies from-zone untrust to-zone nprch policy term01 match destination-address obj-10.160.67.0
set security policies from-zone untrust to-zone nprch policy term01 match destination-address obj-10.160.67.1
set security policies from-zone untrust to-zone nprch policy term01 match destination-address obj-10.160.67.2
set security policies from-zone untrust to-zone nprch policy term01 match application junos-icmp-all
set security policies from-zone untrust to-zone nprch policy term01 match application junos-https
set security policies from-zone untrust to-zone nprch policy term01 then permit
set security policies from-zone untrust to-zone nprch policy term10 match source-address obj-10.1.74.251
set security policies from-zone untrust to-zone nprch policy term10 match source-address obj-10.1.74.252
set security policies from-zone untrust to-zone nprch policy term10 match source-address obj-10.1.74.253
set security policies from-zone untrust to-zone nprch policy term10 match destination-address obj-10.160.67.146
set security policies from-zone untrust to-zone nprch policy term10 match application tcp-445
set security policies from-zone untrust to-zone nprch policy term10 then permit
set security policies from-zone untrust to-zone nprch policy term11 description -=VPNs=-
set security policies from-zone untrust to-zone nprch policy term11 match source-address obj-10.255.1.7
set security policies from-zone untrust to-zone nprch policy term11 match destination-address obj-10.160.67.10
set security policies from-zone untrust to-zone nprch policy term11 match application junos-icmp-all
set security policies from-zone untrust to-zone nprch policy term11 match application tcp-3389
set security policies from-zone untrust to-zone nprch policy term11 then permit
set security policies from-zone untrust to-zone nprch policy term100 match source-address obj-10.1.0.0/16
set security policies from-zone untrust to-zone nprch policy term100 match destination-address obj-10.160.67.0
set security policies from-zone untrust to-zone nprch policy term100 match application any
set security policies from-zone untrust to-zone nprch policy term100 then deny
set security policies from-zone untrust to-zone nprch policy term100 then log session-init
set security policies from-zone untrust to-zone nprch policy term100 then log session-close
set security policies from-zone untrust_corp to-zone untrust policy term01 description To-Internet
set security policies from-zone untrust_corp to-zone untrust policy term01 match source-address obj-10.0.0.0/8
set security policies from-zone untrust_corp to-zone untrust policy term01 match destination-address internet
set security policies from-zone untrust_corp to-zone untrust policy term01 match application any
set security policies from-zone untrust_corp to-zone untrust policy term01 then permit
set security policies from-zone untrust to-zone untrust_corp policy term01 description from-internet
set security policies from-zone untrust to-zone untrust_corp policy term01 match source-address internet
set security policies from-zone untrust to-zone untrust_corp policy term01 match destination-address obj-10.0.0.0/8
set security policies from-zone untrust to-zone untrust_corp policy term01 match destination-address obj-192.168.0.0/8
set security policies from-zone untrust to-zone untrust_corp policy term01 match application any
set security policies from-zone untrust to-zone untrust_corp policy term01 then deny
set security policies from-zone untrust to-zone untrust_corp policy term01 log session-init
set security policies from-zone untrust to-zone untrust_corp policy term01 log session-close
```

итд

Вот так должно выглядеть на форигейт

```
edit 1
set name "untrust_nprch_term01"
set srcintf "untrust"
set dstintf "nprch"
set srcaddr "any"
set dstaddr "obj-10.160.67.0" "obj-10.160.67.1" "obj-10.160.67.2"
set service "junos-icmp-all" "junos-https"
set action accept
set logtraffic disable
next
edit 2
set name "untrust_nprch_term10"
set srcintf "untrust"
set dstintf "nprch"
set srcaddr "obj-10.1.74.251" "obj-10.1.74.252" "obj-10.1.74.253"
set dstaddr "obj-10.160.67.146"
set service "tcp-445"
set action accept
set logtraffic disable
next
edit 3
set name "untrust_nprch_term11"
set srcintf "untrust"
set dstintf "nprch"
set srcaddr "obj-10.1.74.251" "obj-10.1.74.252" "obj-10.1.74.253"
set dstaddr "obj-10.160.67.146"
set service "tcp-445"
set action accept
set comments "-=VPNs=-"
set logtraffic disable
next
edit 4
set name "untrust_nprch_term100"
set srcintf "untrust"
set dstintf "nprch"
set srcaddr "obj-10.1.0.0/16"
set dstaddr "obj-10.160.67.0"
set service "any"
set action deny
set comments "-=VPNs=-"
set logtraffic all
next
edit 5
set name "untrust_corp_untust_term01"
set srcintf "untrust_corp"
set dstintf "unturst"
set srcaddr "obj-10.0.0.0/8"
set dstaddr "internet"
set service "any"
set action permit
set comments "To-Internet"
set logtraffic disable
next
edit 6
set name "untrust_untust_corp_term01"
set srcintf "untrust"
set dstintf "untrust_corp"
set srcaddr "internet"
set dstaddr "obj-10.0.0.0/8" "obj-192.168.0.0/8"
set service "any"
set action deny
set comments "from-internet"
set logtraffic all
next
```

Comment: С какой именно проблемой вы столкнулись? Что значит "Не могу зациклить"?

Comment: Вообще ничего не получается, не получается зауникалить и на основе уникальности строк заполнить "Случай". Возможно нужно в csv вид привести перед этим.... не знаю, недостаточно опыта

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы накапливать данные - придумали списки. Чтобы ассоциировать эти данные с чем-то уникальным - придумали словари.

```
import re
from collections import defaultdict

text = """
встретились кошка и собака они ели рыбу  
встретились кошка и собака они ели крысу  
встретились кошка и собака они ели сыр  
встретились кошка и собака они ели кашу  
встретились кошка и собака они ели картошку  
встретились кошка и собака они вместе играли  
встретились кошка и собака они вместе дрались  
встретились кошка и собака они вместе ссорились  
встретились собака и птичка они ели ряженку  
встретились собака и птичка они ели рябину  
встретились собака и птичка они ели траву  
встретились собака и птичка они вместе танцевали  
встретились собака и птичка они вместе гуляли  
встретились корова и коза они ели рябину  
встретились корова и коза они ели траву  
встретились корова и коза они вместе танцевали  
встретились корова и коза они вместе гуляли  
"""

animals = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list))
for line in text.strip().splitlines():
    anim1, anim2, do, what = re.findall(r"встретились\s+(\w+)\s+и\s+(\w+)\s+они\s+(\w+)\s+(\w+)", line)[0]
    animals[(anim1, anim2)][do].append(what)

for i,(k,v) in enumerate(animals.items(), 1):
    print("Случаай", i)
    print("Встретились:", ", ".join(k))
    print("Ели:", ", ".join(v["ели"]))
    print("Делали:", ", ".join(v["вместе"]))
    print()
```

---

Если файл относительно небольшой, то можно не построчно, а сразу циклом по всем данным.

```
for anim1, anim2, do, what in re.findall(r"встретились\s+(\w+)\s+и\s+(\w+)\s+они\s+(\w+)\s+(\w+)", text):
    animals[(anim1, anim2)][do].append(what)
```

---

Решение абсолютно другой задачи, которая на самом деле оказывается имелась ввиду:

```
import re
from collections import defaultdict

juniper_rules = """
set security policies from-zone untrust to-zone nprch policy term01 match source-address any
set security policies from-zone untrust to-zone nprch policy term01 match destination-address obj-10.160.67.0
set security policies from-zone untrust to-zone nprch policy term01 match destination-address obj-10.160.67.1
set security policies from-zone untrust to-zone nprch policy term01 match destination-address obj-10.160.67.2
set security policies from-zone untrust to-zone nprch policy term01 match application junos-icmp-all
set security policies from-zone untrust to-zone nprch policy term01 match application junos-https
set security policies from-zone untrust to-zone nprch policy term01 then permit
...
"""

fortigate_rules = defaultdict(lambda: {"srcintf"    : None, 
                                       "dstintf"    : None,
                                       "srcaddr"    : [], 
                                       "dstaddr"    : [], 
                                       "service"    : [], 
                                       "action"     : None, 
                                       "comments"   : None, 
                                       "logtraffic" : "disable"})

for rule in juniper_rules.splitlines():
    if not rule: continue   # пропуск пустых строк
    parsed = re.match(r"""\s*set\s+security\s+policies\s+
                            from-zone\s+(?P<from_zone>\S+)\s+
                            to-zone\s+(?P<to_zone>\S+)\s+
                            policy\s+(?P<policy>\S+)\s+
                            (match\s+(?P<match>\S+)\s+(?P<match_arg>\S+)
                            |(then\s+)?(?P<log>log)
                            |then\s+(?P<then>\S+)
                            |description\s+(?P<description>\S+))""", rule, re.X)

    if not parsed:
        print("Строка не распознана: ", rule)
    else:
        name = f'{parsed["from_zone"]}_{parsed["to_zone"]}_{parsed["policy"]}'
        for match, to_item in (("from_zone"  , "srcintf" ), 
                               ("to_zone"    , "dstintf" ),
                               ("then"       , "action"  ),
                               ("description", "comments"),
                               ):
            if parsed[match]:
                fortigate_rules[name][to_item] = parsed[match]
        for match, to_item in (("source-address"     , "srcaddr"),
                               ("destination-address", "dstaddr"),
                               ("application"        , "service")):
            if parsed["match"] == match:
                fortigate_rules[name][to_item].append(parsed["match_arg"])
        if parsed["log"]:
            fortigate_rules[name]["logtraffic"] = "all"

for i, name in enumerate(fortigate_rules, 1):
    print("edit", i)
    print(f'set name "{name}"')
    for item, q in (("srcintf", '"'), ("dstintf", '"'), ("comments", '"'),
                    ("action", ''), ("logtraffic", '')):
        if fortigate_rules[name][item]:
            print(f'set {item} {q}{fortigate_rules[name][item]}{q}')
    for item in ("srcaddr", "dstaddr", "service"):
        if fortigate_rules[name][item]:
            print(f'''set {item} "{'" "'.join(fortigate_rules[name][item])}"''')
    print("next\n")
```

Comment: Да, реально работает. Спасибо. А что, если вместо переменных будут символы? например object-10/102 ? и что, если где ели делали переменные будут пустыми? при отсутствии переменной код выдает ошибку.

Comment: Ну, добавьте проверку. Если элемента словаря (ели) нет, то не выводите ничего. Или берите содержимое через get()  `v.get("ели", [])`. Что за "вместо переменных будут символы" - я не понял про какие "переменные" идёт речь.

Comment: Если элемента словаря нет, то выводит ошибку на строку без последнего слова  "встретились кошка и собака они ели"   anim1, anim2, do, what = re.findall(r"встретились\s+(\w+)\s+и\s+(\w+)\s+они\s+(\w+)\s+(\w+)", line)[0]
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Мне в регулярных выражениях нужно покопаться, если вместо "сыр" "кашу" "рыбу" будут буквенно+символьные значения "akv28!9*#"   "LxaZ%slQ"   "8S*#$Li" итд?

Comment: Если там не только букво-цифры, то используйте, например, `(.+?)` вместо `(\w+)`.

Comment: на самом деле мне нужно перенести конфиг из сетевого устройства джунипер на сетевое устройство фортигейт

Comment: прошу помочь с решением перевода. Просьба звучит глупым, но все же, сижу все новогодние  выходные, ума не хватает

Comment: @Булат А сразу нормально сформулировать задачу - не судьба? Зачем все эти кошки да собаки, если нужно было абсолютно другое?

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое, реально сидел все новогодние праздничные дни, не мог решить задачу. Прошу оставить контакты, хотелось бы хоть чуть-чуть отблагодарить

Comment: вы мне очень помогли, перенес с вашей помощью около 1000 правил, это около 10000 строк. И главное заработало с пол пинка